# Unable to install vscdebugger in visual studio

Tags: r, visual-studio

I'd like to use R in MS Visual Studio.

I use Lubuntu 20.04

I just installed: Visual Studio Version: 1.78.0
Electron: 22.4.8
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-144-generic
Sandboxed: No

My R version is 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)

I tried to install vscDebugger 0.5.2. using the extensions tool.

Once I tried to run a script I received the error message reporting the vscDebugger is not installed

I tried to reinstall it with

```
install.packages(c('R6', 'jsonlite'))
ext install RDebugger.r-debugger
```

Now the extension is marked as "installed" but once i try again to debug a R script I get this error.

*This feature is still somewhat experimental! If this does not work or you want to make sure you have the latest version, follow the instructions in the readme to install the package yourself.
emphasized textError in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘vscDebugger’*